# JavaScript canvas class enemies collide into each other

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection

I have the following class for the creation of my enemies in a canvas board. I use the checkcollision method to avoid walls and the player buty I don't know how to avoid the enemies between them:

```
class Enemy {
    constructor(img, x, y){
        super(img, x, y);
        this.width = 36;
        this.height = 36;
        this.speedX = 0.4;
        this.speedY = 0.4;
        this.dx = 0;
        this.dy = 0;
        this.distance = 0;
        this.angle = 0;
        this.home = true;
        this.scared = false;
        this.dead = false;
    };
    draw(){
        ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };
    checkcollision(object) {
        return (
          this.x < object.x + object.width &&
          this.x + this.width > object.x &&
          this.y < object.y + object.height &&
          this.y + this.height > object.y
        );
    };
    updateAngleX(player, objects){
        this.dx = player.x - this.x;
        this.dy = player.y - this.y;
        this.distance = Math.sqrt((this.dx*this.dx) + (this.dy*this.dy));
        this.angle = Math.atan2(this.dy,this.dx);
        this.x += Math.cos(this.angle) * this.speedX;
        objects.forEach(object => {
            if ((this.dead === false || object.color === "blue") && this.checkcollision(object)){
                if (this.dy > 0){
                    this.y += this.speedY;
                    this.x -= Math.cos(this.angle) * this.speedX;
                    if (this.checkcollision(object)) this.y -= this.speedY;
                } else if (this.dy < 0){
                    this.y -= this.speedY;
                    this.x -= Math.cos(this.angle) * this.speedX;
                    if (this.checkcollision(object)) this.y += this.speedY;
                };
            };
        });
    };
    updateAngleY(player, objects){
        this.dx = player.x - this.x;
        this.dy = player.y - this.y;
        this.distance = Math.sqrt((this.dx*this.dx) + (this.dy*this.dy));
        this.angle = Math.atan2(this.dy,this.dx);
        this.y += Math.sin(this.angle) * this.speedY;
        objects.forEach(object => {
            if ((this.dead === false || object.color === "blue") && this.checkcollision(object)){
                if (this.dx > 0){
                    this.x += this.speedX;
                    this.y -= Math.sin(this.angle) * this.speedY;
                    if (this.checkcollision(object)) this.x -= this.speedX;
                } else if (this.dx < 0){
                    this.x -= this.speedX;
                    this.y -= Math.sin(this.angle) * this.speedY;
                    if (this.checkcollision(object)) this.x += this.speedX;
                };
            };
        });
    };
};
```

And I create 4 enemies like this:

```
enemies = [
        new Enemy(vaccineImg, 460, 290),
        new Enemy(vaccineImg, 400, 290),
        new Enemy(vaccineImg, 520, 290),
        new Enemy(vaccineImg, 580, 290)
    ];
```

How can I avoid the collision between my enemies using their method checkcollision()?
Because right now they collide into each other and become one ... Thank you!

Comment: Easier to do this with a working sample. Maybe try adding a condition to the collision method. `for (let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) { if (object !== enemies[i]) { return (.....)}}`

Comment: And after that? I mean I didn't understand what else is needed after that. For example, if (object === enemies[i]) then?

Comment: Do you have a working example so I can see how you are calling `checkCollision(object)`. Can you make a snippet?

Comment: I call the checkCollision inside the updateAngle methods in the class. Like this: ```enemy.updateAngleX(walls)```